# Default color of mdInput, placeholder

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-material

Is it possible to change the default color of mdInput placeholder in angular**JS** material ?

HTML code is below

```
<md-input-container class="header-inputContainer" floatPlaceholder="never">
    <input class="header-inputBar" mdInput placeholder="荷主" [formControl]="sample" [mdAutocomplete]="autoTxt">
</md-input-container>
```

now it's Grey as you can see " `荷主` ", but I want to color it white like " `Local Development` ".

[image]

I managed to change the color when mdInput is focused, but not the default.

Comment: md-input-container ? What's your version of Angular Material ?

Comment: I think it is 2.0.0-beta.8...

Comment: To do this, I believe you need to use `.foregroundPalette`. An example would be `$mdThemingProvider.theme('default').foregroundPalette['3'] = 'rgba(255,0,0,1)';`. You might have to mess around with the index in the foregroundPalette array to make sure your affecting the right part of the input.

Answer (score 1):

In most browsers, the placeholder text is grey. To change this, style the placeholder with the non-standard `::placeholder` selector.

```css
.header-inputBar{height:40px;border-radius:5px;border:solid 1px gray;font-size:20px;}
.header-inputBar:focus{border-color:red;}
.header-inputBar::placeholder{color:#989898;}
.header-inputBar:focus::placeholder{color:red;}
```

```html
<md-input-container class="header-inputContainer" floatPlaceholder="never">
    <input class="header-inputBar"  placeholder="荷主" />
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: It works if I get rid of `mdInput`, but doesn't work with `mdInput`, but thank you....

Answer (score 0):

Input inside any element is still input. And the codes below to change all input placeholder text color.

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: #fff;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: #fff;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: #fff;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: #fff;
}
```

You can add it as specific element like what you have:

```
input.header-inputBar::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: #fff;
}
input.header-inputBar::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: #fff;
}
input.header-inputBar:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: #fff;
}
input.header-inputBar:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: #fff;
}
```

In case your CSS is overwritten, you can put it with higher priority:

```
.header-inputContainer input::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: #fff !important;
}
input.header-inputBar::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: #fff !important;
}
.header-inputContainer input:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: #fff !important;
}
.header-inputContainer input:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: also it works if I get rid of mdInput, but doesn't work with mdInput, but thank you....